meaning of "in the spoils of the colony" from The Artful Dodger TV series
Some context:
They are on an island near Australia (a colony of Britain) in the 19th century. Lady Fanny Fox wants to marry Dr. Sneed but hopes she isn't being too overt and says:

No man wants to feel trapped, even in the spoils of the colony.

What does "in the spoils of the colony" mean in this context?
I found out that the definition of "spoils" is valuables seized by violence, esp in war, but can't figure out how does the definition fits in this context. Maybe you can help me figure out the meaning of this phrase.
Quote from the 4th episode, 15m 30s mark:

Lady Fanny Fox: Dr. Sneed has been invited to join us for dinner.
We'll be in the second dining room, which fits the evening for its
intimacy. I'm being served on a platter for him. I hope it's not too
pointed. No man wants to feel trapped, even in the spoils of the
colony.
Lady Belle Fox: You want to marry sniffly Sneed, the boy who cried
when we used to tease him?


It's not a common or standard phrase.  I'd guess (but only a guess) that Fanny Fox is classically educated and is alluding to "colony" in it's original sense of "a piece of land awarded to a roman soldier after completion of their commission".
Life on a colony was the easy life, after the hard work of fighting for the Romany Empire, and the spoils of the colony would be the produce of the land.
Whatever the specific allusion, the general sense is clear.  No man wants to be trapped, even being trapped in a comfortable place is worse than being free.

It's a common enough expression. When Columbus refused to allow the Spanish settlers of the West Indies to enslave the natives, they summoned one Francisco de Bobadilla from the homeland. Eager to claim the spoils of the colony for his own, Bobadilla fabricated accusations against Columbus and shipped him and his brothers back to Spain in chains. He then proceeded to establish a reign of slavery, rape, and murder often carelessly attributed to the man he deposed. Web article on The Blaze.com

Also There seems to be absolutely no interest by the federal government
to turn Puerto Rico into a state. On the other hand, there is clearly
an interest in up-righting its finances so that bondholders,
particularly those that speculated by buying what were fast becoming
junk bonds, can get their share of the spoils of the colony. (Oversight hearing of the Committee on Natural Resources, US House of Representatives)

It's interesting to consider how awful imperialism was (and is?).
